# Extra alignment warning change table

Tags: tables, errors, multicolumn

The following error appears in the console:

> Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

but I do not see where is missing in the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=45mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Factors}}
&  \cmidrule{2-3}  
\textbf{Levels}& \textit{Solvent} & \textit{Water:Solvent mass ratio} \\ \midrule
\textit{1} & Water & 0 \\
\textit{2} & ChCl:2Gly & 0.40 \\
\textit{3} & ChCl:2Urea & 0.57 \\
\textit{4} & --- & 0.69 \\
\textit{5} & --- & 0.82 \\
\textit{6} & --- & 0.87 \\
\textit{7} & --- & 0.91 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use `beamer` in the title when your document class is `article`?

Comment: Sorry, it was just an example, in both it gives the same warning, so it has nothing to do with the beamer class specifically.

Comment: Your first row has waaaaaaay more than 3 cells

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first row has an `&` instead of `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=45mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow, array}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Factors}}\\
\cmidrule{2-3} \textbf{Levels}& \textit{Solvent} & \textit{Water:Solvent mass ratio} \\ \midrule
\textit{1} & Water & 0 \\
\textit{2} & ChCl:2Gly & 0.40 \\
\textit{3} & ChCl:2Urea & 0.57 \\
\textit{4} & --- & 0.69 \\
\textit{5} & --- & 0.82 \\
\textit{6} & --- & 0.87 \\
\textit{7} & --- & 0.91 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Sam Carter has shown the fix, but to give a comment on the error message, you only showed a fragment.

The error is:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate 
                        
l.14 &
        \cmidrule{2-3}
?
```

the l.14 tells you that tex was reading line 14, and the linebreak shows how far along the line it had got, so the error is issued immediately after reading the `&` on line 14   which you can then see is starting an undeclared column 4 after `& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Factors}}`

The error message is telling you that tex will interpret that `&` as a `\cr` (`\\` ) which is actually the correct fix in this case (a pretty rare event for TeX recovery actions:-)